# How to upload prc file type?

Tags: uploads, permissions

When I try to upload a `*.prc` file type, I get this error:

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://howto.blbosti.com/2010/03/wordpress-modify-the-upload-list-of-allowed-file-types/) explains a method in which you can add a file type to the list of allowed file types.

Copy and paste the following code into your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    // add your extension to the array
    $existing_mimes['prc'] = 'application/x-mobipocket-ebook';

    // add as many as you like
    // and return the new full result
    return $existing_mimes;
}
```

I didn't tested the code, but I hope it will help you along.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your themes `functions.php` file.
I have tested the code and its working fine.

```
// Add the filter
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');

function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {

    // Add file extension 'extension' with mime type 'mime/type'
    $existing_mimes['prc'] = 'application/x-mobipocket'; 

    // and return the new full result
    return $existing_mimes; 
}
```

For more information see [this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes).